# JMeter Stress testing

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

MAMP server hosting a Joomla instance.

I'd like to hear the community's thoughts on the best way to stress test the server and find it's breaking point on concurrent users etc. Currently I have setup a test plan which I have going to the home page, grabbing the index.php, css, js and all images and have run tests on 1 to 100 users and a varying number of loops.

What I'd like to know is how do I determine at what number of concurrent requests or looping requests is a good way to gauge if my server can handle the proposed increase in traffic?

What is a good KB/sec, Throughput, Average, Max, Min via the Aggregate Report and at what number of threads/loops etc?

I have googled and have not found immediate answers to these questions and thought to come here.

More or less I have just used this http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf to guide me and then I have been winging it in terms of Thread and Loop numbers.

Any light shed on these subject would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's Joomla. It's already broken! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a good number for all those parameters, other than as high as possible for your particular testing subject machine. Just load up as many concurrent connections you can with Jmeter (toying with the balance of instances and threads), and fire to your machine. Do so until a certain component (ie MySQL) fails, then try to optimize that component and fire again.

Comment: I guess I have not really found it to break or at least I don't know what a website breaking looks like. It seems that it just takes longer for the page to load when I'm doing a bunch of concurrent connections. Any pointers on what to be looking for would be extremely helpful.

Comment: It's depends on what your testing requirements are actually. For example, are you trying to measure the maximum concurrent connections that you server can handle, while the response time is within 1 second? Or are you trying to load up 1,000 concurrent connections and make sure that your server is optimized enough for such a load? 

If say, at 1,200 concurrent users, your server no longer respond within 1 second. That's the "breaking point" as per your test plan. Next step would be to optimize your server before you try again. 

You will definitely need to have a test plan of some sort.